# Как обратиться в цикле к элементу?

Tags: javascript

Как мне посредством JS сделать также? То есть к примеру хочу добавить классы DIV под номером 2-3-9

```js
let info = document.querySelector('.info');
let divElem = 11;
for (let i = 0; i < divElem; i++) {
  let column = document.createElement('div');
  column.className = 'column';
  info.append(column);
}
```

```css
.column {
  background: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}
  
.column:nth-child(3) {
  background: blue;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="info"></div>
```

Comment: Ну, вместо 'column' пишите нужный вам класс с нужным вам номером? Или о чём вопрос?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю... Можете подробнее написать. У меня была мысль сделать так: 
column[2].className = 'newClass'; но ошибка в таком случае...

Comment: Вы хотите добавить класс второму, третьему и девятому элементам? Ну тогда проверяйте значение переменной i через if

Comment: Сейчас попробую, спасибо за подсказку)

Comment: Получилось, можете в ответ написать, я поставлю, что Вы ответили. if( i == 2){column.className = 'column-3';}

Answer (score 0):

Легче сделать массив с нужными номерами и проверять наличие числа в массиве, чем писать цепочки проверок if, так:

```js
let info = document.querySelector('.info');
let divElem = 11;
let blueIndexes = [2, 3, 9];

for (let i = 0; i < divElem; i++) {
  let column = document.createElement('div');  
  let color = blueIndexes.includes(i) ? " blue" : "";
  // Обращаю внимание на пробел перед blue
  
  column.className = "column" + color;

  info.appendChild(column);
}
```

```css
.column {
  background: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.column.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="info"> </div>
```